# React-Native split view screen for iPad/Tablet

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I'm having a requirement where I need to implement split view for existing sectionlist navigation screens on iPad/Tablet, I am using react-nativigation(version 4.4.0) in my existing project, I am completely blank on how to implement the navigation in the split view without navigating the complete page, as of now on click to a particular list item, it navigates the complete page to further detail screens, I have managed to split the screen using flexbox, keeping the list view on the left hand side and a blank view on the right side which will show the detail screens with all further navigations on the basis of list item selection on the left side

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out a way to create it using redux state